# Buttons not working with React-Router-Dom V5.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m trying to make nested routing using React-Router-Dom V5.2 and made buttons for them.

Every time I click one of the buttons I'm still stuck on the same page. However, it works if I refresh the browser. I don’t know what happened to this package.

Here's my code :

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/dummy" component={DummyTest} />
        <Route path="/examStart" component={Quiz} />
        <Route path="/summary" component={Summary} />            
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: What buttons? Provide an [mcve]

Comment: please provide more details.